# including facebook.php makes my web shows extra information

Tags: php, facebook

I have read some tutorials related to displaying Facebook name, picture and so on.
To do that I must include (or require) the file "Facebook.php", which I downloaded in latest version from Facebook github web.
The problem is that when I require "facebook.php" my web looks like this:
http://imageshack.us/f/543/facebookphp.png/
The file is supposed to contain functions like getUser() and the Facebook instance, for example, but why has it got all that html code that appear in my web?

Comment: I don't get what you want to ask..

Comment: try http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html good tuts and make easy to integrate